# Postgresql: How to take incremental backup with wal-e

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, database-backups, wal-e

I am new to postgresql. I've connected to my demo database with psycopg2 and inserted data with python faker. I want to take incremental backup with the tool [WAL-E](https://github.com/proteeti13/wal-e) and want to see how it actually works. But the few tutorials aren't helping that much as they're not for naive users.

Can someone help explaining the steps simply how to backup data with WAL-E? That would be a great help ! I'm using psql 10.4 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Python & Dependencies

```
apt-get install python-dev python-virtualenv libevent-dev pv lzop daemontools
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev
sudo apt-get install -y python3-venv
```

Create & Activate Virtual Environment

```
Sudo python3 -m venv /opt/wal-e
source /opt/wal-e/bin/activate
```

Install Wal-e

```
sudo /opt/wal-e/bin/pip install wal-e[aws]
```

Setup Environment Variables

```
umask u=rwx,g=rx,o=
mkdir -p /etc/wal-e.d/env
sudo -i -u root
echo "Your AWS Secret Key" > /etc/wal-e.d/env/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
echo "Your AWS Access Key" > /etc/wal-e.d/env/AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
echo 'Your AWS Region > /etc/wal-e.d/env/AWS_REGION
echo 's3://some-bucket/directory/or/whatever' > /etc/wal-e.d/env/WALE_S3_PREFIX
sudo chown -R root:postgres /etc/wal-e.d
```

Change Postgres Config to Activate Archiving

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
wal_level = replica
archive_mode = on
archive_command = '/usr/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /opt/wal-e/bin/wal-e wal-push %p'
archive_timeout = 60
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

Test Wal-e is Working

```
sudo -i -u postgres
/usr/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /opt/wal-e/bin/wal-e backup-list
```

Now Push Your First Base Backup to S3

```
/usr/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /opt/wal-e/bin/wal-e backup-push /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
```

Now Set the Cron For Regular Backup

```
sudo -i -u postgres 

mkdir logs
touch backup.log
touch deletebackup.log

crontab -e

00 00 * * * /usr/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /opt/wal-e/bin/wal-e backup-push /var/lib/postgresql/10/main > ~/logs/backup.log 2>&1
00 00 * * * /usr/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env  /opt/wal-e/bin/wal-e delete --confirm retain 1 > ~/logs/deletebackup.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Hi @Chandan Singh Gadhwal , thanks for posting simple and step by step procedure. However, for step 5, there is no directory named us envdir when I created that manually and try to test wal-e backup. It's throwing below message:/usr/bin/envdir: Is a directory. Could you please help me to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Hi  Shiwangini, Sorry for the delay. You must need to login with postgres user to access /usr/bin/envdir. Also this is not a directory this is executable file created by postgres. First login with this command sudo -i -u postgres as mention above.